# Sequelize check table is empty

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am using Node js and doing insertion or Updation in a table. How can I check if table is empty using sequelize not thorough sql query.is there a way I can get total no of rows also in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For counting all the rows in a table, you could use the following method ex:

```
Users.findAndCountAll()
.then(result => {
    console.log(result.count);
    console.log(result.rows);
})
.catch(err => {
    throw err;
});
```

I recommend you to search trough the sequelize documentation, here is the link: [Sequelize Documentation](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-usage.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use count:

```
const { count, rows } = await Users.findAndCountAll();
if (count === 0 && rows === 0) {
  // do you thing
}
```